# CORS issue when calling Angular app to node server to spotify api

Tags: javascript, angular, cors

I am trying to create an auth flow via the spotify api. I have an angular app which calls my node server running on localhost:3000.

```
export class SpotifyService {
  private apiRoot = 'http://localhost:3000/login';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login() {
    console.log('login');
    this.http.get(this.apiRoot).subscribe((data) => {});
  }
}
```

This angular app is running on localhost:4000

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: '...',
  clientSecret: '...',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World from Node.js server!');
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  const authorizeUrl = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL([
    'user-read-email',
    'user-read-private',
  ], 'state');

  res.redirect(authorizeUrl);
});

// Callback route
app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query;
  console.log('code: ', code);

  try {
    const tokens = await spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code);
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(tokens.body.access_token);
    spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(tokens.body.refresh_token);
    console.log(tokens.body.access_token);

    // The user is now logged in
    res.redirect('/landing');
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

when i call the node server from my angular application, I get this error:

```
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=...&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&scope=user-read-email%20user-read-private&state=state' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/login') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

on the spotify dashboard, my website is registered to localhost:4000(angular app) and callback on node server localhost:3000/callback.

i thought the cors() function would take care of this

Comment: The message talks about `http://localhost:4200`. 4200 is neither 3000 nor 4000. On a side note, I'm not sure why you want to switch between origins during this request.

Comment: @tevemadar i guess i was just confused by the docs saying i should store the token on the server so i was just routing everything through the server

Answer (score 1):

> CORS issue when calling Angular app to node server to spotify api

You aren't doing that. Well, you are, but then you issue a redirect to tell the browser to make a request directly to Spotify without going through localhost and it is *that* request that you are getting a cross-origin error on.

---

The login flow you are using is **not designed to work with Ajax**.

It should work like this:

1. The browser **navigates** (e.g. with a regular form submission) to `/login` (this means **leaving** the Angular app)
2. Your server redirects them to Spotify
3. Spotify shows them a webpage asking if they want to login with Spotify and reveal personal data (such as their account name) to you
4. They click confirmation on Spotify's webpage which navigates to another Spotify endpoint
5. Spotify redirects them back to `http://localhost:3000/callback` with some parameters you can use to confirm they really did login with Spotify.
6. You then return (or redirect to) an HTML document which reloads the Angular app.

Since Spotify has to show the user a webpage to ask for permission, this **must** be done by navigating the user to Spotify's site and **not** with Ajax.

Comment: Thank you, redirecting via an a tag works